# Django. Создание нового приложения из файла

Tags: python, django, cmd, subprocess

Необходимо из views.py создавать новое приложение. Вижу два варианта решения, но ни к одному не могу подступиться:
1) Через os или subprocess вызвать команду python manage.py startapp {projName}. Но в таком случае вылетает ошибка.
2) Возможно, даже наверняка, в Django есть встроенная функция для создания нового приложения из файла, но отыскать я её пока не могу...

Для более глубокого понимания:
Есть форма, с которой считываются какие-то данные и добавляются в БД. Одно из полей этой формы и будет являться названием нового приложения (странички).

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: 1) какая ошибка? 2) вы уверены, что хотите динамически генерировать джанго приложения?

Comment: Названием приложения или странички? Это разные вещи

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, зачем вам это?

Comment: Ну да, другого варианта пока не углядел. Вдаваясь в подробности: через форму я загружаю данные(ip, port, service и тд) через файл и отдельным инпутом название объекта. Затем, уже на другой страничке необходимо отображать загруженное таблицей(БД). Как поступить без создания нового приложения - не знаю. Вручную добавлять тоже, соответственно, не вариант, так как объектов может быть много.

Comment: @Иванермилов выглядит как костыль. Вы руководство Django прочитали?

Comment: @Иванермилов «отображать загруженное» — одно приложение, один views, выбирающий один нужный объект из БД по переданным параметрам (если нужно), и один шаблон, отрисовывающий таблицу для загруженного объекта. Зачем тут несколько приложений, непонятно;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.core.management import call_command

app_name = 'someapp'
call_command('startapp', app_name, interactive=False)
```